# Realtek Wifi Adapter stops working after 20.04.1 update

Tags: realtek

The original thread is here: [Restored Realtek Adapter Operation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1292580/most-recent-update-of-20-04-knocked-out-realtek-wifi-drivers-how-to-restore/1292624?noredirect=1#comment2213140_1292624)

The Realtek adapter had worked for 3-4 months after a 20.04.1 install until a Nov ubuntu 20.04.1 upgrade. It stopped working immediately afterwards. Following the advice in the first thread, was able to restore operation and it was believed that the DKMS installation would prevent failure in future. But it failed again a few days ago. After an upgrade. I have 2 nearly identical computers and it has been fixed in #2, but not in this computer #1, and I've been asked to post some tests:

dkms status

```
rtl8188fu, 1.0, 5.4.0-52-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux, 1.0, 5.4.0-52-generic, x86_64: installed
```

sudo lshw -C network

```
[sudo] password for jim-hitek:           
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 11
       serial: 10:c3:7b:9d:af:b3
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:40 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fea00000-fea00fff memory:d0800000-d0803fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@2:1
       logical name: wlx1cbfce112175
       serial: 1c:bf:ce:11:21:75
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800usb driverversion=5.4.0-52-generic firmware=0.36 ip=192.168.43.108 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0bda:a811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8811AU 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WLAN Adapter
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1267:0103 Logic3 / SpectraVideo plc G-720 Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 275d:0ba6  USB OPTICAL MOUSE 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 058f:9254 Alcor Micro Corp. Hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

On this computer, that I call #1, the Realtek does not work. On my other computer, that I call #2, operation has been restored following the instructions shown at the link. I believe what the experts are trying to figure out is why didn't installing DKMS protect the Realtek drivers through the upgrade?

Comment: The `dkms` problem that you had was due to the re-installation of `dkms`. We figured that out this morning. If you compare `dkms status` between both machines, you'll see that you have the incorrect drivers installed here. Do `sudo dkms remove rtl8188fu/1.0 --all`, and the same for the other driver. Then follow the instructions in the other question.

Comment: "Same for the other driver"? Can you explain, please?

Comment: `sudo dkms remove rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0 --all`. Then `dkms status` should show nothing... until you install the dkms driver from your other question.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Kernel_Module_Support

Comment: Sadly I show this: DKMS: uninstall completed. And then this dkms status
rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux, 1.0, 5.4.0-52-generic, x86_64: installed:

Comment: No sadly... you properly removed the first driver. Now do the second `remove`, and then `dkms status` will show nothing.

Comment: OKay, that did it. DKMS status returns NULL. I'm off to reinstall from the other instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

dkms [info](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Kernel_Module_Support).

`dkms status` shows...

```
rtl8188fu, 1.0, 5.4.0-52-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux, 1.0, 5.4.0-52-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Both drivers are not the correct ones for the Realtek. We remove them...

```
sudo dkms remove rtl8188fu/1.0 --all
sudo dkms remove rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0 --all
```

Then we follow the instructions at the [previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1292580/most-recent-update-of-20-04-knocked-out-realtek-wifi-drivers-how-to-restore/1292624).

Comment: dkms status
rtl8812au, 5.6.4.2, 5.4.0-52-generic, x86_64: installed
root@MainOffice:/home/jim-hitek/Downloads/Utilities/Realtek Drivers#

Comment: The Realtek Wifi Dongle now works. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: How do I do that?