# Wifi dongle not working

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb, realtek

My wifi dongle stopped working, i previously installed it with this thread:
[Most recent update of 20.04 knocked out Realtek Wifi drivers...how to restore?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1292580/most-recent-update-of-20-04-knocked-out-realtek-wifi-drivers-how-to-restore/1292624) .
But now it stopped working, can someone help me?
Thanks a lot!

DKSM STATUS:

```
nvidia/515.86.01, 5.15.0-60-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia/515.86.01, 5.19.0-32-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8821CU/5.4.1: added
```

SUDO LSHW -C network

```
  *-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: enp4s0
   version: 0c
   serial: b4:2e:99:42:5d:92
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 
   mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.19.0- 
   32-generic firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes 
   port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:34 ioport:f000(size=256) memory:f7500000-f7500fff memory:f2200000-f2203fff
   *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 5
   bus info: usb@1:4
   logical name: enxb6337242e0ec
   serial: b6:33:72:42:e0:ec
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host 
   driverversion=5.19.0-32-generic duplex=half firmware=RNDIS device 
   ip=192.168.198.105 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair
```

lsusb

```
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 258a:0016 BY Tech Usb Gaming Keyboard
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 0bda:c811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC
Bus 001 Device 019: ID 22b8:2e24 Motorola PCS moto g(60)s
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 145f:02a7 Trust GXT 950 Gaming Mouse
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0a5c:2148 Broadcom Corp. BCM92046DG-CL1ROM Bluetooth 2.1 
Adapter
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0a5c:4503 Broadcom Corp. Mouse (Boot Interface Subclass)
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:4502 Broadcom Corp. Keyboard (Boot Interface Subclass)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of 
BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I also use the grep command as suggest in comment but i dont have output:

```
~/rtl8821CU/rtl8821CU$ grep rtw /etc/modprobe.d/*
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `grep rtw /etc/modprobe.d/*` command.

Comment: @Pilot6 I use the command but it didn't give me a output

Comment: Try `sudo dkms install rtl8821CU/5.4.1` and reboot

Comment: It won't build. All I could find is up to 5.17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have installed a driver from some place using  DKMS that is incompatible with the 5.19 Linux kernel.

Ubuntu 22.04 recently upgraded to the 5.19 kernel and the driver doesn't build.

You can boot with a previous kernel with grub menu, and the dongle should work.

The options to get it working permanently are:

1. Find a patched driver that supports the 5.19 kernel, or patch it yourself. Please don't ask how to patch it. If you don't know, then the option is not for you. The driver should work on Ubuntu 22.10, because it uses the same kernel. So it is easier to search.
2. Switch your system to a non-HWE kernel.

Comment: I didn't find a patched driver and i don't know how to do it myself i am recently starting with ubuntu, but i booted from the 5.16 kernel and run the sudo dkms install rtl8821CU/5.4.1 command and now it works, i gonna boot always on this until i find a driver, thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: I am sure someone will patch the driver soon to get it work with 5.19. It is not that hard.